# how to live stream mp3 files using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, real-time, server-side, live-streaming

I want my code in node js to live stream an mp3 file in real time (which means always running on the server).

I wrote this code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mp3'
    });
    var rs = fs.createReadStream('audio.mp3');
    rs.pipe(res);
})
```

The problem is that when I refresh the page, the stream starts all over again.  I want it to act as a live stream so that when I refresh, the page will start in a different position.

Comment: HTTP is not your friend here. Start by looking at HLS streaming.

Comment: @Quentin  HLS is HTTP :)

Comment: @Keith It's HTTP **based**

Comment: @Quentin So HTTP is indeed your friend, as it doesn't work without it. :)   OP: seen as your using node this package might help -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/hls-server